# How to make hash navigation slideTo both parent and child slides in nested swipers?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm using hash navigation for swiper like this:

```
hashNavigation: {
watchState: true,
replaceState: true,
},
```

So I can navigate to slides when I click menu hash links.

Works fine till I nest swipers inside slides. when I use the same hashNavigation settings for both parent and children swipers, only parent links are working as expected. But children links don't activate the parent slide, only the child.

I checked the code from hash-navigation.js, this is the bit that handles the hash change:

```
onHashCange() {
const swiper = this;
const newHash = document.location.hash.replace('#', '');
const activeSlideHash = 
swiper.slides.eq(swiper.activeIndex).attr('data-hash');
if (newHash !== activeSlideHash) {
const newIndex = 
swiper.$wrapperEl.children(`.${swiper.params.slideClass}[data- 
hash="${newHash}"]`).index();
if (typeof newIndex === 'undefined') return;
swiper.slideTo(newIndex);
}  },
```

Is it possible to slide to the parent slide when a child link is clicked? I'm thinking I can add the parent hash to the HTML in a similiar fashoin to data-hash, like parent-data-hash. But I have no clue what would be the JS to get this attribute value and slideTo accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I guess it was probably not implemented to account for nested sliders. (Maybe deliberately, to not encourage the use of such UX catastrophes to begin with? Haha.) I suspect it probably slides the child slider to the correct slide as expected - you just don’t see the effect of it, because the parent does not slide to the correct one containing the child slider accordingly. If that’s the case, then it could probably be added, […]

Comment: […] if you subscribe to an event such as `slideChange` - and then you traverse the DOM upwards from that current slide, to see if the whole thing is nested into another slider. If that’s the case, trigger the parent sliding itself to the correct slide then via code. (No idea however, how well that would work together with watchState / navigation via browser history.)

Comment: You are correct, it is working but I don't see it as the parent don't slide itself.